# Tried to call Provider.of<dynamic>. This is likely a mistake and is therefore unsupported. pos 7: 'T != dynamic'

Tags: flutter, dart

When I click on edit product on my app, it must go to the EditProductScreen where I can edit it, but this error appears (see also the photo):

Tried to call Provider.of<dynamic>. This is likely a mistake and is therefore unsupported.

If you want to expose a variable that can be anything, consider changing `dynamic` to `Object` instead. 'package:provider/src/provider.dart': Failed assertion: line 330 pos 7: 'T != dynamic'

[image]

here are the EditProductScreen (a stateful class) codes :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_shop/providers/product.dart';
import 'package:my_shop/providers/products.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class EditProductScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/edit-product';

  @override
  State<EditProductScreen> createState() => _EditProductScreenState();
}

class _EditProductScreenState extends State<EditProductScreen> {
  final _priceFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final _descriptionFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final _imageUrlFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final _imageUrlController = TextEditingController();
  final _form = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  var _editedProduct =
      Product(id: '', title: '', description: '', price: 0.0, imageUrl: '');

  var _initValues = {
    'title': '',
    'description': '',
    'price': '',
    'imageUrl': '',
  };
  var _isInit = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _imageUrlFocusNode.addListener(_updateImageUrl);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    if (_isInit) {
      final productId = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String?;
      if (productId != null) {
        _editedProduct =
            Provider.of(context, listen: false).findById(productId);
        _initValues = {
          'title': _editedProduct.title,
          'description': _editedProduct.description,
          'price': _editedProduct.price.toString(),
          //'imageUrl': _editedProduct.imageUrl,
          'imageUrl': '',
        };
        _imageUrlController.text = _editedProduct.imageUrl;
      }
      _isInit = false;
    }
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _imageUrlFocusNode.removeListener(_updateImageUrl);
    _priceFocusNode.dispose();
    _descriptionFocusNode.dispose();
    _imageUrlFocusNode.dispose();
    _imageUrlController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _updateImageUrl() {
    if (_imageUrlFocusNode.hasFocus) {
      setState(() {});
    }
    if ((!_imageUrlController.text.startsWith('http') &&
            !_imageUrlController.text.startsWith('https')) ||
        (!_imageUrlController.text.endsWith('png') &&
            !_imageUrlController.text.endsWith('jpg') &&
            !_imageUrlController.text.endsWith('jpeg'))) {
      return;
    }
  }

  void _saveForm() {
    _form.currentState!.save();
    if (_editedProduct.id != '') {
      Provider.of<Products>(context)
          .updateProduct(_editedProduct.id, _editedProduct);
    } else {
      Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false).addProduct(_editedProduct);
    }
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('edit product'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            onPressed: _saveForm,
            icon: const Icon(Icons.save),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Form(
            key: _form,
            child: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                TextFormField(
                  initialValue: _initValues['title'],
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Title'),
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                  onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_priceFocusNode);
                  },
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value!.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Please enter a valid value!';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  onSaved: (value) {
                    _editedProduct = Product(
                        id: _editedProduct.id,
                        isFavorite: _editedProduct.isFavorite,
                        title: value ?? '',
                        description: _editedProduct.description,
                        price: _editedProduct.price,
                        imageUrl: _editedProduct.imageUrl);
                  },
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  initialValue: _initValues['price'],
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Price'),
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  focusNode: _priceFocusNode,
                  onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_descriptionFocusNode);
                  },
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value!.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Please enter a valid price!';
                    }
                    if (double.tryParse(value) == null) {
                      return 'Please enter a valid number!';
                    }
                    if (double.parse(value) <= 0) {
                      return 'Please Enter a number greater than zero!';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  onSaved: (value) {
                    _editedProduct = Product(
                        id: _editedProduct.id,
                        isFavorite: _editedProduct.isFavorite,
                        title: _editedProduct.title,
                        description: _editedProduct.description,
                        price: double.parse(value ?? ''),
                        imageUrl: _editedProduct.imageUrl);
                  },
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  initialValue: _initValues['description'],
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Description'),
                  maxLines: 3,
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                  focusNode: _descriptionFocusNode,
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value!.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Please enter a description';
                    }
                    if (value.length < 10) {
                      return 'Should be at least 10 characters long!';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  onSaved: (value) {
                    _editedProduct = Product(
                        id: _editedProduct.id,
                        isFavorite: _editedProduct.isFavorite,
                        title: _editedProduct.title,
                        description: value ?? '',
                        price: _editedProduct.price,
                        imageUrl: _editedProduct.imageUrl);
                  },
                ),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                        width: 100,
                        height: 100,
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, right: 10),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.grey)),
                        child: _imageUrlController.text.isEmpty
                            ? const Text('Enter a URL!')
                            : FittedBox(
                                child: Image.network(_imageUrlController.text),
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              )),
                    Expanded(
                      child: TextFormField(
                        decoration:
                            const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Image URL'),
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.url,
                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                        controller: _imageUrlController,
                        focusNode: _imageUrlFocusNode,
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (value!.isEmpty) {
                            return 'Please enter a valid image URL!';
                          }
                          if (!value.startsWith('http') &&
                              !value.startsWith('https')) {
                            return 'Please enter a valid URL!';
                          }
                          if (!value.endsWith('png') &&
                              !value.endsWith('jpg') &&
                              !value.endsWith('jpeg')) {
                            return 'Please enter a valid image type!';
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                        onSaved: (value) {
                          _editedProduct = Product(
                              id: _editedProduct.id,
                              isFavorite: _editedProduct.isFavorite,
                              title: _editedProduct.title,
                              description: _editedProduct.description,
                              price: _editedProduct.price,
                              imageUrl: value ?? '');
                        },
                        onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                          _saveForm();
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be this. give the provider class. Try this

```
   Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false).findById(productId);
```

Comment: now works. Thanks for your prompt assistance.